# !Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> when attempting 3dpdf

Tags: pdftex, 3d, movie15, csname

I'm trying to make a 3d pdf image, and get this error.  I'd appreciate any advice.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\includemovie[
    poster,
    toolbar, %same as `controls'
    label=cylinder.u3d,
    text=(cylinder.u3d),
    3Daac=60.000000, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.000000 -16.490000 0.000000, 3Droo=16.490000, 3Dcoo=-0.000000 5.000000 0.000000,
    3Dlights=CAD,
]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{cylinder.u3d}
\end{document}
```

The Error shows:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \message 
l.13 ]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{cylinder.u3d}
```

The .u3d and .tex files is output from Meshlab v2020.07, where I have modeled a simple cylinder.

[link to miktex set up log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpc64q5wj83yufx/miktex-report.txt?dl=0)

[link to .u3d file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5si6dbekmpicwr/cylinder.u3d?dl=0)

[link to folder with various log files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7p9g8cv22e7j614/AADvhKRCasXUiDG1JqusC-9Ja?dl=0)

[The method I used to try to create this 3d pdf](https://husseinbakri.org/how-to-embed-interactive-3d-models-movies-and-sound-clips-into-a-pdf-via-latex/)

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 1):

`movie15` is obsolete. Instead, use `media9`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{tikz} % for creating a poster
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
    activate=onclick,
    3Dtoolbar,
%    label=cylinder.u3d,
    3Dmenu,
    % found by right-click on 'Generate Default View'
    3Daac=60.000001669652114,
    3Dcoo=1.1920928955078125e-7 5.000276565551758 0,
    3Droo=11.489760585373341,
    3Dlights=CAD,
  ]{%
    \tikz\node[draw,minimum width=0.5\linewidth,minimum height=0.5\linewidth]{\ttfamily(cylinder.u3d)};
  }{cylinder.u3d}
\end{document}
```