# Problem to embed u3d file in pdf

Tags: errors, hyperref, 3d, posters, media9

I am beginner with latex code and I want add 3d object in my pdf.
I find this code but I have this following error :
! Missing \endcsname inserted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\layout}{0}
\newcommand{\pname}{testvrmlstream3.u3d}
\newcommand{\moviewidth}{297mm}
\newcommand{\movieheight}{210mm}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\centering
\includemovie[
poster,
toolbar,
label=\pname,
text=(\pname),
3Daac=60.000000, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.004411 -0.158060 0.000000, 3Droo=0.158122, 3Dcoo=0.004411 0.010763 0.000000,
3Dlights=CAD,
]{\moviewidth}{\movieheight}{\pname}

\end{document}
```

Can you help me ?
Thank you

Comment: There was the answer.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572316/missing-endcsname-inserted-to-be-read-again-when-attempting-3dpdf/572338#572338?newreg=130e8302384745878916194833ba52f7